# How to use a cookie to transfer database information from one page to another using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I am a complete begginier to ASP.NET framework and have very little knowledge of how MVC works, my task is to create a database in MVC with the following informations-

```
ASP.NET:
public class Charity
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public Double Amount { get; set; }
        public Double TaxBonus { get; set; }
        public String Comment { get; set; }
    }

    public class CharityDBContext : DbContext //controls information in database 
    {
        public DbSet<Charity> Donations { get; set; } //creates a donation database
    }
```

The last class is used to create the database, the database itself works. However I want the user to be displayed the Database information on the second page using a cookie after they click on the Donate Now Button -

```
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Donate Now", "Create")
</p>
```

How can a cookie be created in MVC? should I create a new Class? or a new Controller? sorry about this, the lecturer in university hasnt really taught us much as this is a new subject.

Comment: Why not send the ID as a route parameter to the "Create" page and fetch it from the database? Surely it's more efficient to get it from your high-performance database than pass it back and forth over a consumer Internet connection.

Comment: Thanks for the help:)

Comment: N.b. that means not using a cookie at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[More Information](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576514/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusVariousplus)

As far as my knowledge serves me well, four different methods exist to handle passing data between controllers in asp.net MVC. They are 1. ViewData 2. ViewBag 3. TempData and 4. Sessions.

Code in the first controller:

```
TempData["sendFlag"] = sendStoredInfo;
return RedirectToAction("LoginFailed");
```

Code in the second controller:

```
public ActionResult LoginFailed()
{
   bool sendFlag = TempData.ContainsKey("sendFlag")? TempData["sendFlag"]: false;
}
```

or in your redirect try with

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Nome", new{ username: username})
```

but the action of your controller must have as argument the (string username) like

```
public ActionResult Index(string username)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: `ViewData` and `ViewBag` cannot be used for passing information between controllers. And `TempData` is `Session`